# How do I access my AWS-hosted DynamoDB tables on my development machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection-string, amazon-dynamodb

I have some DynamoDB tables hosted on AWS. I would like to query these tables from my development machine for analysis. However, I cannot find a connection string (or any connection information for that matter) in the AWS web console.

How do I connect to DynamoDB on AWS from my own machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DynamoDB does not have a connection string.

Instead, you use one of the various AWS SDKs (in the language of your choice) along with your AWS IAM user access key and secret pair.

The SDKs include the methods to query your DynamoDB tables.

Comment: This complicates the usual database development practices. Sure it may increase the security, but also increases the barrier to entry.